# Replace ajax response with current text

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want the ajax response to replace the current text but it is appending on the top. My html page is:

```
<html>
<head>
      <h2>This is a test</h2>
      <script type="text/javascript" >

      function ajaxFunction()
      {

        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
         {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         }
        else
         {// code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
         {
           if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
          }

       xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxinfo.php",true);
       xmlhttp.send();
     }


       window.onload = function one(){
         var a1 = [1,2,3];
         for (var i=0;i<a1.length;i++) {
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.innerHTML = a1[i];
            p.onclick = ajaxFunction;
            document.body.appendChild(p);
          }

       }

      </script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="myDiv"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My `ajaxinfo.php` is:

```
<?php
     $display=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Maruti","Bugatti");

     for($i = 0; $i <sizeof($display);$i++){
        echo $display[$i].'<br/>';
      }

 ?>
```

What I am getting currently is the ajax response is displayed above the `a1` array but I want the ajax response to replace the current array display. So that the initial display is:

```
//Here goes the heading display
   1
   2
   3
```

My final display onclick is:

```
 //Here goes the heading display
   Volvo
   BMW
   Toyota 
   Maruti
   Bugatti
```

Don't want the previous array to be displayed here anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not change:

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
```

To select your div?

```
var p = document.getElementById('myDiv');
```

Then just remove the call to appendChild.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    var p = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    p.innerHTML += a1[i];
    p.onclick = ajaxFunction;
}
```

Comment: In this case, only the last element of the array is displayed which is `3`.

Comment: it's because you are doing `document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = a1[i]` on the same element (get by id), so each iteration replaces the content set from the previous one.

Comment: Do you suggest some alternative method?